# How to add 2 minutes delay between jobs in a queue?

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire

I am using Hangfire in ASP.NET Core with a server that has 20 workers, which means 20 jobs can be enqueued at the same time.

What I need is to enqueue them one by one with 2 minutes delay between each one and another. Each job can take 1-45 minutes, but I don't have a problem running jobs concurrently, but I do have a problem starting 20 jobs at the same time. That's why changing the worker count to 1 is not practical for me (this will slow the process a lot).

The idea is that I just don't want 2 jobs to run at the same second since this may make some conflicts in my logic, but if the second job started 2 minutes after the first one, then I am good.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: How are you adding jobs to hangfire? are you using the ```BackgroundJob.Enqueue()``` method?

Comment: @fsbflavio I am using  RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(), since users choose if they want the job to run daily, weekly, monthly, etc... I am using hangfire for developing a report scheduler, and having some issues when starting to generate 2 reports at the same exact time. [Note: I don't control the start time, but I just want to avoid 2 jobs from starting at the same minute, that's it]

Comment: Perhaps you could use a flag in your database. A table with column 'lastExecutionTime' updated when a job is started, so every job has to go to that table and check if the current time is 2 minutes greater than the 'lastexecutintime' if is, update 'lastexecutiontime' and run. if not wait 2 minutes before trying again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BackgroundJob.Schedule()` to run your job run at a specific time:

`BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello"), dateTimeToExecute);`

Based on that set a date for the first job to execute, and then increase this date to 2 minutes for each new job.

Something like this:

```
var dateStartDate = DateTime.Now;
foreach (var j in listOfjobsToExecute)
{
    BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => j.Run(), dateStartDate);
    dateStartDate = dateStartDate.AddMinutes(2);
}
```

See more here:
https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/calling-methods-with-delay.html?highlight=delay

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this is not practical at all, users control their job times, not me, I just need to prevent 2 jobs from running at the same exact time. And I am using  RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate() by the way, since users choose if they want the job to run daily, weekly, monthly, etc... I am using hangfire for developing a report scheduler by the way, and having some issues when starting to generate 2 reports at the same exact time.